# salesforce how to query with lookup fields value

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

There is a course object with a marketing location lookup field. Marketing location object has state and country fields.

how could i query from the course object with the marketing location objects field?

```
QueryResult qr = binding.query("select CourseName__c, 
     (select State__c,Country__c from Marketing_Location__c) from Course__c")
```

It's not work.....

I'm new to salesforce, so any help, thanks.

Comment: have a look at this blog post, i found it very helpfull when learning soql myself not too long ago.http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When queryign parent you use direct notation, not a subquery sicne there can be only one parent

```
QueryResult qr = binding.query("select CourseName__c, 
     Marketing_Location__r.State__c,
     Marketing_Location__r.Country__c from Course__c")
```

also, custom object names always use __c suffix (two underscores)

Comment: thanks, but still got the error: Didn't understand relationship 'Marketing_Location__r' in FROM part of query call

Comment: Go to Setup | Create | Objects | Marketing_Location object. 
Edit Course__c lookup field, check the Child Relationship Name.
Append __r to that name and use that

Comment: thanks:) i have try to do that, the child relationship name is "Courses", so i updated my query to :select CourseName__c,  (select State__c, Country__c from Courses__r) from Course__c, but there still error about :Didn't understand relationship 'Courses__r' in FROM part of query call..

Comment: Hmm, you got me confused now. Which object has a lookup into which object? Does Course have a lookup into Marketing Location or vice versa?

Comment: Course object has a Marketing Location field , marketing location field is a lookup data type.:)

Comment: ok, then you are not querying the children you are querying a parent obejct (becasue parent is the one you point to with lookup). I'll update the answer

Comment: hi mmix, thanks a lot, it works. but i still got a question , when i debug, i noticed that the Marketing_Location__r.State__c innertext is not the same as courseName__c, is there some method to make the marketing_location__r.State__c just display the value of the state?

Comment: because i use the partner wsdl, so i may need to use innerText to get the value.marketing_location__r.State__c  and marketing_location__r.Country__c seems has combined into one result field.